# Convergent functions and integrals

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

Let $V$ be real normed vector space of Riemann integrable functions $f : [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ with norm

$||f||:=\sup\{|f(x)|:x\in[0,1]\}$.

Let $f_n:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and let there be a function $f\in V$ such that

$\lim_{n\to\infty} ||f-f_n|| = 0$.

**I have to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1f_n(x)dx=\int^1_0f(x)dx$.**

I have already shown that $f$ is continous.

My strategy:

Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1f_n(x)dx -\int^1_0f(x)dx = 0$

so $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1(f_n(x) - f(x))dx = 0$.

I then think I have to use the squeeze theorem:

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\inf_{[0,1]}(f_n(x) - f(x)) \leq\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1(f_n(x) - f(x))dx \leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{[0,1]}(f_n(x) - f(x))$

Is it then allowed to put the limit inside the supremum and infimum, which makes them both equal to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost done, just modify the last line as 
$$0\leq \left|\int_0^1(f_n(x) - f(x))dx\right|\leq \int_0^1\left|f_n(x) - f(x)\right|dx \leq \sup_{[0,1]}\left|f_n(x) - f(x)\right|$$
then use $\sup_{[0,1]}\left|f_n(x) - f(x)\right|=\|f-f_n\|\to 0$
and apply the squeeze theorem.

P.S. Following your approach, you need
$$-\sup_{[0,1]}\left|f_n(x) - f(x)\right|\leq\inf_{[0,1]}(f_n(x) - f(x)) \leq \int_0^1(f_n(x) - f(x))dx\\ \leq \sup_{[0,1]}(f_n(x) - f(x))\leq\sup_{[0,1]}\left|f_n(x) - f(x)\right|$$
and again use $\sup_{[0,1]}\left|f_n(x) - f(x)\right|=\|f-f_n\|\to 0$.

Comment: How does the limit fit into this?

Comment: Take the limit of both sides and you are done. Recall  then $\sup_{[0,1]}\left|f_n(x) - f(x)\right|=||f-f_n||\to 0$

Comment: Alright! And the absolute value bars? Where did they come from, how did you transform it into this?

Comment: This is the monotony property of integrals: $|\int_I f(x)dx|\leq \int_I |f(x)|dx$

Comment: I edited my P.S. Any further doubt?

Comment: I understand the monotony property. So what you're doing is stating that the absolute value of the integral is equal to 0, and therefore the integral itself is equal to 0?

Comment: After the squeeze theorem, I state that  the LIMIT of the absolute value of the integral is equal to 0, and therefore the LIMIT of integral itself is equal to 0

Answer (score 1):

> Is it then allowed to put the limit inside the supremum and infimum, which makes them both equal to 0?

You can't switch infimum/supremum and the limit in general.

Consider $f_n(x)=\max\{0,1-|x-n|\}$. Then $\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|f_n(x)|=1$ while $\lim_{n\to\infty} |f_n(x)|=0$. Hence,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|f_n(x)|=1\neq 0=\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}\lim_{n\to\infty} |f_n(x)|.
$$

But your case is a bit more special because $[0,1]$ is compact and $f_n$ and $f$ are continuous. Hence, the infimum and supremum are achieved at some points. Then you can apply the limit as your last step.

Answer (score 0):

The map $f \mapsto \int_0^1 f(x)\,dx$ is continuous w.r.t your norm $\|\cdot\|$.

Indeed, it is linear and bounded:

$$\left|\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx\right| \le \int_0^1 |f(x)|\,dx \le \int_0^1 \|f\|\,dx  = \|f\|$$

Therefore $f_n \xrightarrow{\|\cdot\|} f$ implies $ \int_0^1 f_n(x)\,dx \to  \int_0^1 f(x)\,dx$